# chart labels don't scale when saving ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

long time reader, first time asker!

I'm trying to save a bunch of plots from ggplot using the `ggsave` command, but the labels are not adjusting proportionately to the plot size.

For example, using the iris dataset:

```
data(iris)

iris$study.number <- sample(1:5, replace=T)

ggplot(iris) + aes(x=study.number, fill=Species) +
  geom_bar(position="stack") 

ggsave("iris.png", scale=3)
```

While the plot in the image saved is three times larger than what's shown in the viewer, the labels continue to be very small. I've tried just manipulating the length and width arguments, to no avail.

I would prefer to use `ggsave` if possible (it's been much easier than other options for saving plots, but if it's only possible using something else I'm definitely open to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chart labels don't really scale the same way other plot elements do. A workaround is modifying the text size in the ggplot itself. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)

iris$study.number <- sample(1:5, replace=T)

ggplot(iris) + aes(x=study.number, fill=Species) +
    geom_bar(position="stack") +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 60))

ggsave("iris.png", scale=3)
```

The line `theme(text = element_text(size = 60))` increases the fontsize of all labels.

Comment: Do you have a sense of what a good calculation might be for the appropriate size vs scale, or do I have to tinker? I had a feeling this might be the answer, but increasing the text size like that makes the preview plot pretty useless.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any suggestions for that. I often encounter exactly this issue when creating plots and I've learned to just not even look at the plot previewer anymore. Something you could try is opening a new window with the specified width and height (on windows you can use `x11(width, height)`). As long as that new window is the active graphics device, the plot will be drawn there. Perhaps that speeds up the tinkering a bit.